# Observer is triggered twice even though the observed variable is changed once

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, observer-pattern

My `ViewModel` class should load `User` data and an image asynchronously, when done it should set a variable `userLoaded` to true and trigger the observer inside the hosting fragment to inflate the options menu. The initialization inside the `ViewModel` is done via

```
init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userLoaded.value = false
            try {
                loadUser(id)
                loadImg(id)
            } catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e(TAG, "${e.message}")
            } finally {
                userLoaded.value = true
            }
        }
    }
```

`loadUser()` and `loadImg()` are two `suspend fun` that load some data from `Firebase`. The main problem is that, even though `userLoaded.value` is changed only once, the menu is inflated twice. The following is the observer inside the fragment

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        // menu.clear()
        viewModel.userLoaded.observe(this, Observer {
            if (it == true) {
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.show_profile_menu, menu)
            }
        })
    }
```

Update1:
How about this solution?

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
        viewModel.userLoaded.observe(this, Observer {
            menu.findItem(R.id.edit_icon).isVisible = it
            menu.findItem(R.id.edit_icon).isEnabled = it
        })
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not subscribe to the observer in `onCreateOptionsMenu` because this method may be called multiple times. You should instead subscribe in `onViewCreated`,

```
fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   /* other stuff */
   viewModel.userLoaded.observe(this, Observer {
        if (it == true) {
            // toggle a global flag and recreate the menu
            hasLoaded = true
            activity?.invalidateOptionsMenu()
        }
    })
}
```

then

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    // menu.clear()
    if (hasLoaded) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.show_profile_menu, menu)
    }
}
```

Comment: please check my Update1, is there any problem doing that?

Comment: You should not do it in onPrepareOptionsMenu because that also may be called multiple times. Is there some reason you can't do it in onViewCreated?

Comment: I cannot invalidate the entire options menu but only one item

Comment: I'm not certain why that is a problem, when you invalidate the menu it gets recreated, whatever didn't change will be inflated as it was before and only what you decide to change will change. Without more context I can't be more specific on the solution.